# Несколько значений массива из 1 input

Tags: javascript

задача простыми словами:
Есть пустой массив.
Есть инпут и кнопка.

-Пользователь вводит ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЕ в инпут (Например: Привет! Как дела?)
-Нажимает кнопку
-В массив записывает ТРИ значения "привет!" "как" "дела?" (без пробелов. и желательно еще и без знаков :), но пока хотя бы просто без пробелов).

Понимаю как передать общее значение.

В принципе понимаю как передать по 1 символу в значения.
А как заставить его понимать слова по отдельности?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript**

```js
document.getElementById("btn_test").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let ar = document.getElementById("test").value.split(' ');
  let ar2 = ar.map(function(name) {
    return name.replace(/[^а-яё]/gi, '');
  });
  console.log(ar2);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test">
<button type="button" id="btn_test">Тест</button>
```

**Jquery**

```js
$("#btn_test").on("click", function() {
  let ar = $("#test").val().split(' ');
  let ar2 = ar.map(function(name) {
    return name.replace(/[^а-яё]/gi, '');
  });
  console.log(ar2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test">
<button type="button" id="btn_test">Тест</button>
```

Документация:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: **Ё**корный бабай не пройд**ё**т ;-)

Comment: @UModeL обновил, теперь все **Ё** содержащее пройдет )